# how do i insert more one record from json in Mywebservice

Tags: php, json, api

```
this my json
{
"title":"covid today",
"body":"this is body",
"author":"m.ratt",
 "category_id":"50"
}
```

this my code

```
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();
$post = new Post($db);
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
$post->title = $data->title;
$post->body = $data->body;
$post->author = $data->author;
$post->category_id = $data->category_id;

if($post->create()) {
  echo json_encode(
  array('message' => 'Post Created')
  );
  } else {
   echo json_encode(
    array('message' => 'Post Not Created')
  );
 }
```

I can insert only one record on my database .if i want to insert more incase send JSON in 2 or 3 member array  .How do i can do that? I suppose I have to get count array and loop insert for that one. but I no idea to fix it! .Anyone help me please? Thank u

Comment: You can loop through each member array and save the data.

Comment: thank u but i try it not work

Comment: Can you share what have you tried?

Comment: I try to push in postman on 2 array json {
      "ppk":[
        {"title":"covid today",
  "body":"this is body",
  "author":"m.ratt",
     "category_id":"50"}],
      "ppk1":[
        {"title":"covid today",
  "body":"this is body",
  "author":"m.ratt",
     "category_id":"51"}]
    }
  
    but get count 1  this is my code $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();
  $post = new Post($db);
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  
  print_r($data);
  echo "count is:".count($data);

Comment: Yes you will get count 1 becoz you are count main array, and which is single. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON like this in you postman

```
{
  "ppk": {
    "title": "covid today",
    "body": "this is body",
    "author": "m.ratt",
    "category_id": "50"
  },
  "ppk1": {
    "title": "covid today",
    "body": "this is body",
    "author": "m.ratt",
    "category_id": "51"
  }
}
```

And update your code

```
$datas = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  

$database = new Database(); 
$db = $database->connect(); 
$success = false;

foreach ($datas as $data){
    $post = new Post($db);
    $post->title = $data->title;
    $post->body = $data->body;
    $post->author = $data->author;
    $post->category_id = $data->category_id;
    if($post->create()){ 
        $success = true; 
    }else{
        $success = false;
    }
}

if($success) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Post Created'));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Post Not Created'));
}
```

Comment: I try again it show <br><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: datas in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php_rest_myblog-master/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/php_rest_myblog-master/api/post/create.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
{"message":"Post Not Created"}

Comment: Have you remove the variable in `$datas = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));  ` this line. It is `$tadas`

Answer (score 0):

Thank u ,I try again with your code .It's work.I find the way in many website for fix it.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.